# Polarization of W boson or Z boson

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, polarization, large-hadron-collider

It is known that the massive gauge bosons W and Z have 3 states of polarization-one longitudinal and two transverse. So is it possible that by any means we can decrease it longitudinal polarization and increase its transverse component?//
Or should I increase its velocity to get this required change?

Comment: Have a look  here http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/~thomson/partIIIparticles/handouts/Handout_13_2011.pdf

Comment: @annav Thanks! I had seen this one. My question is if suppose I have a longitudinally polarized W boson. Can I change it to transverse polarization?

Comment: As W decay very fast , no time for manipulation. You can choose events where the W polarization was longitudinal or transverse.  The momentum seems to play a role and it could be used in the choicing.